# Bootstrap Carousel shrinks the images on mobile

Tags: html, css, jekyll, carousel

Firstly, I am trying to build a website using Jekyll. I don't know anything about HTML, CSS etc. I am just using a template that I found online.

I have a carousel on my homepage, I have load different images into it, all of different sizes. When I view the website on my laptop, the images look perfect. But when I view the website on my mobile, the image's width changes, changing the aspect ratio and hence making the image look bad. I know that the mistake is in the code for the carousel (I have explicitly mentioned the height of the images to be 400p and set the width to be auto. My intention behind  fixed height for the carousel is to prevent the text below the carousel to keep moving up and down when different images of the carousel are loaded.

Can someone please help me out on dynamically changing the height of the images of the carousel based on the viewport.

The HTML and SCSS for the carousel is

```css
/* Carusel */

.carousel {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div markdown="0" id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000" data-pause="hover" data-touch="true" >
    <!-- Menu -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" markdown="0">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/slider7001400/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:auto; height: 400px; margin: auto" alt="Slide 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="item ">
            <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/slider7001400/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:auto; height: 400px; margin: auto" alt="Slide 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/slider7001400/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:auto; height: 400px; margin: auto" alt="Slide 3" />
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/slider7001400/4.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:auto; height: 400px; margin: auto" alt="Slide 4" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/slider7001400/5.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:auto; height: 400px; margin: auto" alt="Slide 5" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/slider7001400/6.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:auto; height: 400px; margin: auto" alt="Slide 6" />
        </div>
         <div class="item">
            <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/slider7001400/7.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:auto; height: 400px; margin: auto" alt="Slide 7" />
        </div>
    </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I tried some of the solutions that were mentioned here, but they don't seem to work. Hoping that someone in this thread will be able to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Are your pictures in portrait or landscape orientation?

The problem with landscape pictures and a height of `400px` is, that carousel limits the width of the pictures not to be wider than the screen.

So, for example you have an image of `2000px` wide and `800px` high - what you would want is `1000px * 400px`. Since your screen is not `1000px` wide, width is set to whatever your mobile device can display and the height is still `400px`, because you say so.

[edit]
The last four lines of your scss format the image as well. In order to keep your code simpler, you should delete `style="width:auto; height: 400px; margin: auto"` on the indvidual images and edit your scss as follows:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  max-height: 400px;
  width:100%;
}
```

We don't need the `margin: auto` and `width:auto` as they don't do anything (at least when I try to recreate your project).

If you don't want your content that follow the carousel to jump up and down when having different sized images, you should just add another container around the whole carousel and give it a height of `400px`

```
<div style="height:400px;">
 <div markdown="0" id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000" data-pause="hover" data-touch="true" >
  [...]
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nah, it still doesn't work. The problem arises with Portrait mode, with the Landscape mode on the phone the pictures look pefect

Comment: Have you added [style="width:auto; height: 400px; margin: auto"]? Because the last four lines in your scss format the same object. Try deleting these last four lines. Though the formatting on the element is more important than that in the scss. Also after deleting these lines, try replacing width:400px by max-width:400px again

Comment: Did you mean replace height with max-height? I replaced that, though that preserves the aspect ratio of the images, what it does is, as we view all the images in the carousel the text just below the carousel keeps moving up and down. I want the text to also stay at the same place

Comment: I have edited my above answer and hope that it now does what you expect. I have tried to recreate your project, unfortunatley that left some question: First: What version of Bootstrap is your template using? It doesn't really matter if you don't change it, but be aware that your code won't work in Bootstrap 4.0.0 or above as the classes have been renamed. Second question: With the current answer above, the left/right arrows and indicators jump up and down to be vertically centered. Do you want that, or do you want them static (and often outside the picture)?